# Windows cannot access \\servername from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: file-sharing, windows-server-2008-r2, computer-name

I recently set up a new Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit machine in a network which is predominately XP and Server 2003.

- After a reboot, `\\servername` works
- A while later, `\\servername` -> `"Windows cannot access \\servername"`
- `\\192.168.1.xx` works
- `\\servername.full.domain` works

So, I've got work-arounds, but I'd still like to know why short-name resolution is failing.

Comment: How is your DNS, DHCP and NetBIOS set? Do the event logs report something?

Comment: Both machines in question are statically assigned and Domain Controllers (hence DNS servers)  I enabled NETBIOS on 2008 server.  Found "Automatic certificate enrollment for local system failed" in event logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a lot like this issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/228877/windows-server-2008-r2-loses-ability-to-connect-to-network-share

Comment: Yeah, that looks about right, thanks.  And yet... its not eligible for duplicate status.